# pgAgent installation with Stack Builder in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, installation

I have installed PostgreSQL 9.1 on ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. I try to run Aplication Stack Builder and install pgAgent.

At first I am asked for root password, which I provide, after I choose PostgreSQL 9.1 on port 5433 as the only option. On next screen I tick pgAgent and click Next a few times to get to the Setup screen with verification the postgradeSQL installation details. The Host is local, the User Name is postgres and I type my password for postgrade which I use when open pgAdmin III. When I click next I have a warning:

`psql.bin: could not connect to server: Connection refused`

`Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connection on port 5432?`

When I try pgAdmin it does work with password I provide but it looks for me like this password is not accepted by Stack Builder. I also provide my root password on the beginning so it should be able to do everything with sudo privilege. I don't know what to do now and what is the problem. Should I run something else before Stack Builder?

I know it seems like password problem but I tried all and it is not a simple password case. Did anyone have similar problem or know what to do?

Comment: Cross-post of http://askubuntu.com/questions/215525/pgagent-installation-in-postgresql/215600#215600

Comment: ... *AND* cross-posted to http://stackoverflow.com/q/13323936/398670 as well

Comment: It's good to see you got your answer on all three sites :) now we know that the problem was a simple typo I'm closing the question because it is too specific to be helpful to other visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write:

> I choose PostgreSQL 9.1 on port **5433**

The error message says:

> Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>   TCP/IP connection on port **5432**?

Emphasis mine. Who is wrong? Seems like you are connection to the wrong port / db cluster.